# Rails has_many not populated on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've run a migration to introduce a new `has_many` and `has many :through` association. A "standard" has _many "layers" through "layers_assoc". The new feature works fine on existing standards, but creating a new standard, no new layers or layers_assocs are created.

Despite creating the association and the migration having the defaults, do I have to create instances of the association when the standard is created?

Here is the migration for the layers_assocs table

```
class CreateLayersAssocs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :layers_assocs do |t|
      t.timestamps
      t.integer :layer_id, :null => false      # has_many
      t.integer :standard_id, :null => false   # has_many
      t.boolean :visible, :default => true
    end

    add_index :layers_assocs, :layer_id
    add_index :layers_assocs, :standard_id

    LayersAssoc.reset_column_information

    puts "== Populating LayersAssoc table ============================"
    Standard.all.each do |standard|
      Layer.all.each do |layer|
        begin
          LayersAssoc.create!(
            standard_id: standard.id, 
            layer_id: layer.id, 
            visible: true
          )
        rescue
          puts "== Failed to populate standard_id: #{standard.id} with layer_id: #{layer.id} "
          continue
        end
      end
    end
    puts "== Finished Populating LayersAssoc table ==================="
  end

  def down
    drop_table :layers_assocs
  end
end
```

There's some extra stuff in there to help in case the migration goes wrong on production. After creating the standard, it says `undefined method 'visible'`. Then checking the database I can see that the most recent standard is not in the layers_assocs table.

Here's the models. The parts of standard.rb that matter:

```
has_many :layers_assocs
has_many :layers, :through => :layers_assocs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :layers_assocs
```

layers.rb:

```
has_many :layers_assocs
has_many :standards, :through => :layers_assocs
```

layers_assoc.rb:

```
belongs_to :standard
belongs_to :layer
```

**Update 2:**
I've all but solved this issue. The LayersAssocs get created with their defaults just fine, but I had nothing establishing the default layer associations for standards. I've written those default associations into a `before_filter` on the new method and it works just fine. However, despite having a populated `layer_id`, when the standard is saved, the layer ID disappears.

Example LayersAssoc after LayersAssoc.new loop:

```
#<LayersAssoc id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, layer_id: 1, standard_id: nil, visible_authors: true, visible_reviewers: true>
```

Upon standard.save:

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'layer_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `layers_assocs` (`created_at`, `layer_id`, `standard_id`, `updated_at`, `visible_authors`, `visible_reviewers`) VALUES ('2013-05-13 21:49:36', NULL, 112, '2013-05-13 21:49:36', 1, 1)
```

This is truly confounding.

Comment: Please provide the code you use to create.

Comment: Added. I would insert the `LayersAssoc.create` block in the standard model create action but that strikes me as unnecessary.

Comment: I believe it has to do with a lack of `attr_writter` somewhere on the standard, layer or layers_assoc model.

Comment: Please add the model code too. If it is a lack of attr_writter: Just add it to the model and see if it works.

Comment: I think the attr_whatever's are all taken care of with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on the standard model. I'm now looking for a way to show a form on the new standard view which would add to the params, then parse the params and call `LayerAssoc.new`. The lack of created defaults still bothers me though.

Comment: Please take the time to read http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/activerecord_chapter.html

Comment: The translation for that document makes it a little hard to read. I'm also running rails 3.1.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LayersAssocs objects could be created with their defaults just fine, but I had nothing to establish the default layers (through layers associations). In the migration, this code established the default for existing standards:

```
Standard.all.each do |standard|
  Layer.all.each do |layer|
    begin
      LayersAssoc.create!(
        standard_id: standard.id, 
        layer_id: layer.id, 
        visible: true
      )
    rescue
      puts "== Failed to populate standard_id: #{standard.id} with layer_id: #{layer.id} "
      continue
    end
  end
```

That default needed to be translated to the new action on the standards controller. I was missing all sorts of Rails conventions though and it took me a few days to figure it out. A create action both initializes *and* saves an object to the database. The new action just initializes the objects and then calling `.save` commits it to the DB. So, in the standards controller on a `before_filter` for the new action:

```
@standard = Standard.new
@organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
@standard.organization = @organization

# Create default layers associations
@default_layers = []
for i in 1..5 do
  @default_layers << LayersAssoc.new(layer_id: i)
end
@standard.layers_assocs = @default_layers
```

Once those `LayerAssocs` objects are initilized, you can show a form for them on the new page:

```
<%= form_for(@standard) do |form| %>
  ...
 <%= form.label t('standard.layers') %>
 <table class="table table-striped span4">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td><strong><%= t('standard.layer') %></strong></td>
       <td><strong><%= t('type.authors') %></strong></td>
       <td><strong><%= t('type.reviewers') %></strong></td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <% @standard.layers_assocs.each do |assoc| %>
       <%= form.fields_for :layers_assocs, assoc do |layer_field| %>
         <tr>
           <%= layer_field.hidden_field :layer_id, :value => assoc.layer_id %>
           <td><%= t(assoc.layer.name, :default => assoc.layer.name) %></td>
           <% if assoc.layer_id == 1 %>
             <td><%= layer_field.check_box :visible_authors, :disabled => true %></td>
             <td><%= layer_field.check_box :visible_reviewers, :disabled => true %></td>
           <% else %>
             <td><%= layer_field.check_box :visible_authors %></td>
             <td><%= layer_field.check_box :visible_reviewers %></td>
           <% end %>
         </tr>
       <% end %>
     <% end %>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 ...
```

Notice the hidden field for `:layer_id`. **The only thing submitted to the standard model for creation are the values of the form.** If you initialize the layer_id in the before filter then don't include it on the form, it will be nil when `standard.save` is called and creating a new standard won't work.

Hope that helps someone!